# Regex for fragment url, but not whole

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I would like to have some regular expression to my JS script.

Examples of urls that should not match:

```
http://www.domain.com/files/pictures/3749832
C://mydocuments/files/pictures/3749832
domain.com:8080/doc/files/pictures/3749832
```

BUT these should match:

```
files/pictures/3749832
/files/pictures/3749832
```

My regex: `files/pictures/[0-9]{7}` is not enough good :(

Comment: Can you add a second regex to chedk for http://?

Comment: I can, but what to do with the rest of not matching addresses such as C:// and comain.com/ ? Over that I don't know what is before /files/pictures ... I must ignore urls: http:// C:// domain.com etc.. BUT NOT string: "some normal text and suddenly /files/pictures/373894"

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape the front slashes in order to get it to work. You'll also want to ensure it matches the start of the string (with or without /) - using the `^` matches the start of line.

```
^\/?files\/pictures\/\d{7}
```

Here's a regex101 for you to play around with: https://regex101.com/r/gF5cA0/1

If you need it to also not match anything after this (like a subfolder) use the `$` to match the end of line:

```
^\/?files\/pictures\/\d{7}$
```